# cxf jaxrs registering many resources strategy

Tags: jax-rs, cxf, cxfrs

We want to expose many restservices(hundreds and more) using cxf jaxrs. My question is about the best practises. Should I use only one `JAXRSServerFactoryBean` and register all my resources to this or should I make different server instances(divide them logically) and manage them separately? What if I need to set service spesific timeout, interceptor, feature etc. Is it possible to do so in single server/many resources mode ?